# EclipseLink/JPA: Merge on detached object tree causes primary key violation in child object

Tags: jpa, merge, eclipselink, primary-key, entitymanager

I have a problem with JPA and detached entity objects passed from outside the application via JSON deserialization.

I deserialize an object graph from JSON (passed through a HTTP POST request) and then try to update an existing entity from it.

As far as I understand JPA, using `EntityManager.merge()` on an object should automatically and recursively (depending on `cascade`) attach it and issue an UPDATE to the DB for all the objects in the tree.
However, this apparently only works well for 1) a single entity with no children or 2) the topmost entity in an object graph.

For the child entities, JPA will always issue an INSERT INTO, regardless if the object is already there, and thus run into a primary key violation.

What am I doing wrong?

The relevant part of the implementation is this:

In `AdminResource.java`:

```
@Autowire
protected CustomerConfigDAO customerConfigDao; // wrapper for the JPA persistence

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void storeConfigurationData(CustomerConfigEntity config) {
    customerConfigDao.update(config); // calls EntityManager.merge(...)
}
```

In `CustomerConfigEntity.java`:

```
@Entity
public class CustomerConfigEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String customerID;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customerConfigEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private DefaultValues defaultValues;

    /* ... snip ... */

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void fixBackReference() {
        if(this.defaultValues != null)
            this.defaultValues.setCustomerConfigEntity(this);
    }
}
```

In `DefaultValues.java`:

```
@Entity
public class DefaultValues implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerID", referencedColumnName = "cloudID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private CustomerConfigEntity customerConfigEntity;

    /* ... snip ... */

}
```

Someone suggested to drop the bi-directional one-to-one relationship in favour of a uni-directional one, but since `customerConfigEntity` is both the foreign AND the primary key in `DefaultValues`, removing it would require me to introduce a surrogate key. I did this by introducing an auto-incremented key, but the result was that JPA would create a new record in DEFAULTVALUES whenever a `CustomerConfigEntity` was saved.

Comment: Show the update method and try to add some debugging statements to it to show what is in the object graph you are merging. Merge is expected to work in this simple use case, and EclipseLink has unit tests that show it does. Try setting EclipseLink logging to Finest and see if it queries for your entities when performing the merge.   A quick fix would be to perform a find operation on the entities within update call, since any JPA provider would have to do so anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by eliminating all the bi-directional relationships and replacing them with unidirectional ones.

In `CustomerConfigEntity.java`:

```
public class CustomerConfigEntity implements Serializable {

   // ...

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "customerId", referencedColumnName = "customerId")
   private DefaultValues defaultValues;

   // ...

}
```

Note that one must not use `mappedBy` here.

In `DefaultValues.java`:

```
   @Id
   private String customerId;
```

`CustomerConfigEntity` has some more relationships which are all of the `@OneToMany` cardinality.

For those, I did the same thing but had to use `@JoinColumn` instead of `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` for `customerId` - despite the fact that the `customerId` **is** part of the primary key of the child entity. But using `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` caused JPA to create join tables, which is not what I wanted.

However, I still don't know how I would have to solve this if I really needed bi-directional relationships.